# Try Catch not noticeable using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a simple webpage called mytestpage and am using the following code:

```
@using System
@using System.Drawing
@using System.IO

  try
  {
    int d = 1/0;
    <p>Error not caught</p>
  }
  catch(Exception notUsedForTesting)
  {
    <p>Error caught</p>
  }
```

Instead of seeing "Error caught" text on mytestpage, my site redirects to a differing page as follows: Error.cshtml?aspxerrorpath=/mytestpage.

I would like to know how to avoid this re-direct, and handle the exception my self.

My current web.config file contains:

```
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error.cshtml"/>
  </customErrors>
```

I have tried:

```
  <customErrors mode="Off">
  </customErrors>
```

as well, and I get the same redirect result.

Comment: This will result in a compilation error which means your try is not being run.  If you change your erroneous line to one which throws an exception manually it should hit your catch.

Comment: Shazam, that did it - thank you stephen.vakil.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested it locally. It seems like the error you are getting is not a division by zero exception but rather a compile error

What happens is that your page will be compiled on the fly since you did not enable precompile. So when you navigate to the page it will trigger a compile but that `1/0` immediately error out. Your try catch logic did not even execute.

Try doing a `throw new Exception();` instead of `1/0` and it should work as expected

However I would discourage you from doing complex logic directly inside View. You should try to move the try catch logic into ViewModel or at least controller level